# Python MySQLdb execution of multiple statements from a file without parsing

Tags: python, mysql-python

Is it possible to apply a MySQL batch file using Python mysqldb library. So far I tried to "execute" the content of the file:

```
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute(file(filename).read())
cur.commit() # and without commit
```

This works only on a single statement. Otherwise I get the error:

```
Failed to apply content. Error 2014: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

I intend supporting any kind of MySQL schema, table changes so parsing the file line by line is not an option. Is there other solution than calling mysql client from Python?

Comment: Try `for statement in file(filename).read().split(';')):
cur.execute(statement)` ?

Comment: Thanks. That would definitely work for simple statements, but i'd rather not parse the file. I don't want to mess with the structure of the file if I can help it. For now I can - calling directly mysql client, but thought there could be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using the cx_oracle? 
The issue is due to calling a non existant method in cursor where as it should have been called in connection. 
It should have been

```
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute(file(filename).read())
    connection.commit()
```